# Can't get jQuery Nav working in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mobile, navigation

I'm creating a mobile navigation for my website using jQuery to hide/reveal child links. Here is a working example of the navigation:
http://codepen.io/johnmotyljr/pen/HGADn

However, when I place the javascript into the HEAD of my WordPress theme, it doesn't seem to work. Here is the code I'm using in my theme:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('ul.menu > li > a').click(function(e) {
    $('ul.sub-menu').slideUp('normal');
      if($(this).next('ul.sub-menu').is(':hidden') === true) {    
        $(this).next('ul.sub-menu').slideDown('normal');
      }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}); 
</script>
```

I rarely use Javascript/jQuery so I'm sure it's probably something small holding me up. Anyone want to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```

This is what solved it for me. Thanks for the help from barakadam and loQ. I had to use the Google CDN to over-ride the default WP jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you did not forget to add this line in your head section?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I bet you you forgot to include the jQuery script... just add this line. So your code should be something like this (just copy-paste everything, it works - I tested it - and the script is inside the head section) :

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Document sans titre</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            /*
            *  $(document).ready(function() { });
            *  is the same as
            *  $(function() { });
            */

            $(function() {
              $('ul.menu > li > a').click(function(e) {
                $('ul.sub-menu').slideUp('normal');
                  if($(this).next('ul.sub-menu').is(':hidden') === true) {    
                    $(this).next('ul.sub-menu').slideDown('normal');
                  }
                e.preventDefault();
              });
            });


            /*
             *  Page reference: http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/20608/mobile-navigation-dropdown#Item_10
             */
            </script>

            <style>
            #main-nav_responsive {
                display:block;
                z-index: 99;
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 95%;
            }

            #main-nav_responsive li {
                list-style:none;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding-top: 2px;
            }

            #main-nav_responsive ul {
                padding: 0px;
                height: auto;
                z-index: 10000;
            }

            #main-nav_responsive ul li a {
                display: block;
                color:white;
                text-decoration:none;
                font: normal 18px "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
                text-align: left;
                margin: 0;
                text-transform:capitalize;
                background: #ED1C3F;
                padding: 9px 0px 11px 20px;
                text-transform:lowercase;
            }

            #main-nav_responsive ul li a:hover {
                background:#E35959;
            }

            #main-nav_responsive .sub-menu li a {
                background: #35342f;
            }

            ul.sub-menu {
                display:none;
            }

            </style>
            </head>

            <body>
            <div id="main-nav_responsive">
              <div>
                <ul class="menu">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Specialties</a> 
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#" >Consumer Packaged Goods</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" >Grocery Stores</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" >Resorts + Hospitality</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" >Education</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" >New Product Development</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>


            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-522"><a href="#" >Services</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">

                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-523"><a href="#" >Advertising</a></li>

                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-538"><a href="#" >Branding</a></li>

                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-524"><a href="#" >PR</a></li>

                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-525"><a href="#" >Online</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-527"><a href="#" >Events</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>


            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-643"><a href="#" >Results</a></li>


            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-645"><a href="#" >About</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-531"><a href="#" >Who We Are</a></li>

                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-532"><a href="#" >How We Work</a></li>

                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-533"><a href="#" >Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>


            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-534"><a href="#" >Contact</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">

                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-535"><a href="#" >Careers</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: WP automatically comes with jQuery installed, you have to call it in the head using this:
    `<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>`

Which I have in the HEAD. But since adding that seems to make it work, I'm assuming the enqueue function is not working correctly with my theme.

Comment: I added the call for the jQeury script in the head and the navigation does indeed start to work, however I'm worried about the jQuery conflicting with other plugins. Which is why I would really like to use `<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>` if possible.

Comment: jQuery is loaded by default, so you don't have to do anything. You don't need to put `wp_enqueue_script("jquery");` in your `header.php`. The main question is : can you rely on WordPress version of jQuery? If not, you have to follow the procedure indicated hereafter by IoQ, but start with `wp_deregister_script('jquery')` to deregister WordPress version, then register your version with `wp_register_script`, then use `wp_enqueue_script`.

Comment: I would prefer to use the default version of WordPress as that seems to be the best way to avoid conflicts. However, something is keeping that from happening.

Comment: I decided to use your solution and use the Google CDN to call jQuery, everything is working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

calling a jquery library with this function `<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>` isnt enough. You have to hook it using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action. If youre really concern in jquery conflicts then follow this and put this code in your functions.php

```
//function to call jquery
function install_jquery(){      
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
}

//finally, the action hook to put jquery library in your theme
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'install_jquery');
```

Comment: This combined with @barakadam note above is what solved it for me.